# Grails: Empty lines when using g:sortableColumn on empty column values

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, gsp

I'm having a bug while trying to sort a table using g:sortableColumn in GSP file (grails framework). 
At start, I getting 10 lines as default sorted by default column, and it works fine. 
 
The problem is when there is column which all of it's cells are empty (so we don't have what to sort actually) when clicking on the column which defined as g:sortableColumn, the result is 0 lines instead of 10

The sorting is passed to this code below in the 'params' parameter:

```
Adjustment.findAllByRatecard(linearRateCardInstance, params)
```

And when trying to sort an empty column, the result is a list with 0 elements, maybe it's related to GORM issue, I don't really know.

Column definition:

```
<g:sortableColumn property="channel.name" title="${message(code: 'adjustment.channel.label', default: 'Channel')}"/>
```

Domain definition:

```
class Adjustment
{
    AdjustmentType adjustmentType
    LinearRateCard ratecard
    Channel channel
    Program program
    Genre genre
    Date startDate
    Date endDate
    Integer dow
    DayPart dayPart
    Integer startTime
    Integer endTime
    LinearEventType eventType
    CommercialExternalType commercialType
    PriceCategory priceCategory
    Float adjustment
    String externalId

    static belongsTo = [ratecard: LinearRateCard]

    static constraints = {
        channel nullable: true
        program nullable: true
        genre nullable: true
        startDate nullable: true
        endDate nullable: true
        dow nullable: true
        dayPart nullable: true
        startTime nullable: true
        endTime nullable: true
        eventType nullable: true
        commercialType nullable: true
        priceCategory nullable: true
        adjustment validator: { value, obj ->
            (value > -100)
        }
        externalId nullable: true
    }
}
```

What can I do to fix this ?

Comment: don't be so shy and show us more code

Comment: Okay, this is the column definition: **<g:sortableColumn property="channel.name" title="${message(code: 'adjustment.channel.label', default: 'Channel')}"/>**

Anything else ?

Comment: update your answer, it's difficult to read as a comment. add also the essentials of your domain class

Comment: what `SQL command` do you see in the logs when you call `Adjustment.findAllByRatecard(...)`

Comment: which log? how can I see it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63041/discussion-between-injecteer-and-roey-golzarpoor).

Comment: in the `DataSource.groovy` add/uncomment the lines:
`hibernate {
  cache.use_second_level_cache = true
  cache.use_query_cache = false
  cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
//  show_sql=true
//  format_sql=true
}` then you will see the SQL output in the console

Comment: all are the same as you are said it to be.
are the show_sql and format_sql need to be unmarked?

Comment: I can see that i'm getting **order by (channel1_.name) asc limit ?**

Comment: you should be able to re-run this query in a SQL-console and see if it gives any results back

Comment: It remains the same, 0 results

Comment: that means, that your domain model is not perfect. In general, you shouldn't sort by joined fields.

Comment: It's strange, cause this is a very common query that i'm making in whole of my system. How can avoid this to happened?